# Ranges for hyperparameters in sci-kit models

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameters, scikit-optimize

I'm using sci-kit optimise to choose the hyperparameters. Is there anyway of finding the range of the values a hyperparameter can take?

E.g. number of neighbours in KNN is always in the range [1, number_of_instances]